# MongoDB, поиск по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, node.js, mongodb

Добрый день!
В документе есть поле `size` (строка) вида `134-140`, `140-146` и тп. Делаю запрос

```
var s = "134";
var reg = new RegExp (`[${s}]`, "i");
collection.find({size:{$regex:reg}}).toArray(function(err, result){
                console.log(result);
});
```

По идее, должно вернуть все документы, где в поле `size` встречается цифры `134` (точнее строка). Но возвращает абсолютно все документы. Что я делаю не так?

П.С. после многочисленных тестов я  определил, что возвращаются не все документы, а только те, где встречается хотя бы один символ из регулярного выражения.  В данном случае  `134`. Так, будто квадратных скобок нет.
Версия MongoDB-сервера 3.0, модуль версии 3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var reg = /134/;

collection.find({
  size: {
    $regex: reg,
    $options: 'i'
  }
})
```

**UPD:**

```js
var s = "134";

var reg = ".*" + s ".*";


collection.find({
  size: {
    $regex: reg,
    $options: 'i'
  }
})
```

Comment: Да, так работает. Но мне надо, чтобы регулярное выражение формировалось динамически, через переменную. А так не работает. На Вашу конструкцию переменную тоже пробовал "натянуть"

Comment: @Дмытрык есть такой вариант..

Comment: Второй вариант работает. Спасибо. Не могли бы Вы пояснить, почему мой вариант не работает, а Ваше (не регулярное выражение) работает?

Comment: @Дмытрык думаю документация объяснит лучше : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions

Comment: C.Raf.T - Вы получили доп.баллы? А то мне пришло сообщение: "Вы должны присудить награду..." П.С.: первый раз конкурс объявляю)

Comment: @Дмытрык все ок. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Так как не ответили выше, в чём ошибка, дополню. У вас в регулярном выражении строка вида `[123]`, то есть ищется любой из указаных в скобках символов. Вы это сами заметили:

> после многочисленных тестов я определил, что возвращаются не все
>   документы, а только те, где встречается хотя бы один символ из
>   регулярного выражения. В данном случае 134

А что вы ожидали от квадратных скобок?

> Так, будто квадратных скобок нет.

Почитать об этом можно, например, вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges) или [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Да, регулярные выражения, не мой конек). Я на 100% был уверен, что квадратные скобки  группируют символы и должен осуществляется поиск именно группы символов, как одного слова.

Comment: Нет, для этого (поиск именно группы определённых символов) нужно их записать просто без скобок, один за другим. Если среди них нет особых символов вроде ".", "*" и т. д.